# Normalize deviceorientation data

Tags: javascript, android, ios, gyroscope, device-orientation

I'm playing with deviceorientation in JavaScript and I noticed some differences between my Ipad (iOS 6.1) and my Nexus7 (Android 4.2.2).

This code does not print the same data with the Ipad and the Nexus7.

```
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    <button id="calibrate">Calibrate</button>
    <button id="stop">Stop</button>
    <button id="play">Play</button>
    <div id="log"><p></p></div>
    <script>
      var log = document.getElementById('log');
      var calibrate = false;
      var calibrateG = 0, calibrateB = 0, calibrateA = 0;

      var deviceorientation = function(e) {
        if (calibrate) {
          calibrateG = e.gamma;
          calibrateB = e.beta;
          calibrateA = e.alpha;
          calibrate = false;
        }

        var gamma = parseInt(e.gamma - calibrateG);
        var beta = parseInt(e.beta - calibrateB);
        var alpha = parseInt(e.alpha - calibrateA);

        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = gamma + ' ' + beta + ' ' + alpha;
        log.insertBefore(p, log.firstChild);
      }

      document.getElementById('stop').onclick = function() {
        window.removeEventListener('deviceorientation', deviceorientation);
      };
      document.getElementById('play').onclick = function() {
        window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', deviceorientation);
      };
      document.getElementById('calibrate').onclick = function() {
        calibrate = true;
      };

      window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', deviceorientation);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

At start Android print 0 0 270 and iOS 0 0 0.

Then when I move both in the same way, they don't print the same values.

Can someone explain why, and if there are a way to normalize the data.

UPDATE #1

I already try some calibrations and I care about landscape/portrait.
To reproduce, you can take the code above, put ipad and nexus7 in portrait in front of you.
Calibrate the value of both (first button).
Then take the right corner of the tablet and rotate it until the tablet reaches 90 degrees.
The tablet should be on the left side.

On Android the gamma goes from 0 to -80 and then jump to 270.
On IOS the gamma goes from 0 to -180 without any jump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need all three for an application or game you could prompt the user to ~"hold there device up straight" and record the initial values, then get offsets (deltas) of those values. You could even save that initial calibration to localStorage so it doesn't need to be repeated.

If all you need is landscape or portrait just compare window.innerWidth with window.innerHeight or something equally as trivial.

Comment: I already try to calibrate the value and I care about landscape portrait. I updated my post maybe it's clearer.

Comment: @charles - forget about the alpha, beta, gamma and just use something simple like //// var orientation = window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight ? "landscape" : "portrait"; ////

Comment: I want to know when the user flip/tilt/shake the phone, so I need alpha, beta, gamma. With "I care about landscape portrait" I wanted to say that I already know that landscape/portrait affect alpha, beta, gamma.

Comment: @charles - One browser isn't supporting the current spec and the other is. For example Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Detecting_device_orientation) has alpha [0, 360] beta[-180, 180] gamma[-90, 90]. The way you are calibrating needs to take these ranges into consideration.

Comment: I think the way Firefox is doing it is the right one: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source-orientation.html Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 5):

[Full Tilt JS](https://github.com/richtr/Full-Tilt-JS) normalizes the data values between Android and iOS deviceorientation implementations. It also ensures deviceorientation data remains consistent whenever the user rotates their screen.

[This article](https://dev.opera.com/articles/w3c-device-orientation-usage/) provides a summary of some of the techniques used in the Full Tilt JS library.

Disclaimer: I am the author of both the article and library above. Please give it a try and report any issues directly on the Github project.